# Webscraping in R: Why does my loop return NA?

Tags: r, loops, web-scraping, rvest

I've posted about the same question before here but the other thread is dying and I'm getting desperate.

I'm trying to scrape a webpage using rvest etc. Most of the stuff works but now I need R to loop trough a list of links and all it gives me is NA.

This is my code:

```
install.packages("rvest")

site20min <- read_xml("https://api.20min.ch/rss/view/1")

urls <- site20min %>% html_nodes('link') %>% html_text()
```

I need the next one because the first two links the api gives me direct back to the homepage

```
urls <- urls[-c(1:2)]
```

If I print my links now it gives me a list of 109 links.

```
urls
```

Now this is my loop. I need it to give me the first link of urls so I can read_html it

I'm looking for something like: "https://beta.20min.ch/story/so-sieht-die-coronavirus-kampagne-des-bundes-aus-255254143692?legacy=true".

I use break so it shows me only the first link but all I get is NA.

```
for(i in i:length(urls)) {
  link <- urls[i]
  break
} 
link
```

If I can get this far, I think I can handle the rest with rvest but I've tried for hours now and just ain't getting anywhere.

Thx for your help.

Comment: Is it because `i:length(urls)` should be `1:length(urls)`? Better yet, `seq_along(urls)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try out

```
for(i in 1:length(urls)) {
  link <- urls[i]
  break
} 
link
```

instead?

Comment: this is it. you made my day!